# automatically reconnect ethernet

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

I had some trouble with my switch hub, where ubuntu server systems are connected via ethernet. Now, i saw after solving the problem on my switch, the ubuntu servers (headless) are still disconnected. I had to restart the servers manually.

I there a solution (without cron jobs tricks etc.) to let the ubuntu servers automatically reconnecting the ethernet interface?

Comment: I've written a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect or do something else.